# Having difficulty in iCarousel importing image

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, icarousel

apple beginner here. Im currently studying and trying the iCarousel by nickLockwood. Im planning on putting images in the iCarousel. So here's my .m and .h code:

// .m

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize images;
...

- (void)awakeFromNib
{    
    if (self) {

        //set up carousel data
        //wrap YES = infinite loop
        wrap = YES;

        self.images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"apple.jpg",@"lemon.jpg",@"orange.jpg",@"melon.jpg",@"mango.jpg",nil];       
            }

}


- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{   
    if (view == nil)
{

        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:index]]];
}
    return view;

}
```

// .h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate>{

NSMutableArray *images;
...
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *images;
…
@end
```

I was planning on adding 30 images so I want the code to be maintainable.
My problem is I want to be able to get the image by NSBundle or from the applications directory, I've tried different codes but the image doesn't appear in the carousel. Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you set the delegate and datasource?   it's good as i seen

Comment: Yes I've already set it.

Comment: so what's your problem, no views appears or just empty views?

Comment: did you implement  - (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel ?

Comment: When I tried getting the images via NSBundle, its just empty views. So Im stuck implementing the images manually. Then I was planning on importing images from camera roll so I wanted to try it, but then its just empty views.

Comment: @adali, yes I have implemented those. I have return the value with [images count].

Comment: did you set - (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel ?

Comment: yes, return it with 500.

Comment: .....so weird, or use UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileToLoad ofType:@"jpg"]];  to get image from NSBundle   ?

Comment: maybe first you should set your imageview's backgroundColor to black to check if the imageview is put on then screen, then check if the image is loaded

Comment: and there's a problem in your code, view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:index]]];    ,,  here leaks, you should make it "autorelease" :)

Comment: It says,implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString' is disallowed with ARC.

Comment: oh, you use ARC,     what says?

Comment: Where should I put the autorelease part? It says the error above

Comment: if  you don't use ARC, just [view autorelease];

Comment: So what seems to be causing the problem, or what is an alternative way?

Comment: set the UIImageview's bgcolor to black first to check if the view if created and shown?  did you checked this?

Comment: maybe the problem is the UIImage is not loaded

Comment: yes I have tried it but then no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "UIImage is not loaded"?

Comment: you tried and nothing appear?   show more code, how did you init the iCarousel view?  if you change the bgcolor and still nothing, it's not the UIImage problem

Comment: How can I show you the whole implementation code?

Comment: you didn't set the delegate and datasource?          carousel.delegate = self;
        carousel.dataSource = self;
        carousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;carousel.vertical = NO

Comment: It is set in the iCarousel.h and .m file that is included in nicklockwoods, then I imported it in my project.

Comment: no, you should set it where you use the iCarousel, and did you put the iCarousel onto your ViewController'View?

Comment: #import "iCarousel.h" -- like this?

Comment: Please move extended discussions to [chat].

Comment: Did you include the images in your xCode project?  If not, they will not load.  Step through your code and make sure you are getting valid UIImageView objects as well.

Comment: Are you loading the images from `NSDocumentDirectory`?

Comment: @Kobe.o4 yes im trying to import from the application directory.

Answer (score 1):

Hey here is some code of mine that i used in my iCarousel app. You are missing some methods. So here they are.

```
#pragma mark iCarousel methods

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return [items count];
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfVisibleItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //limit the number of items views loaded concurrently (for performance reasons)
    //this also affects the appearance of circular-type carousels
    return 7;
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[items objectAtIndex:index]]];
    return view;

}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPlaceholdersInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //note: placeholder views are only displayed on some carousels if wrapping is disabled
    return  0;
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel placeholderViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[items objectAtIndex:index]]];
    return view;

}

- (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //usually this should be slightly wider than the item views
    return ITEM_SPACING;
}

- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel itemAlphaForOffset:(CGFloat)offset
{
    //set opacity based on distance from camera
    return 1.0f - fminf(fmaxf(offset, 0.0f), 1.0f);
}

- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform
{
    //implement 'flip3D' style carousel
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, M_PI / 8.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    return CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, 0.0f, offset * carousel.itemWidth);
}

- (BOOL)carouselShouldWrap:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return wrap;
}
- (void)carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation:(iCarousel *)aCarousel
{    
    [labelDescription setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [descriptions objectAtIndex:aCarousel.currentItemIndex]]];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How about from the main bundle?

Comment: O ya and add carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2; in your viewDidLoad

Comment: its already done. my problem is uploadingg images from NSBundle or from camera roll. thanks

Comment: You don't need most of the methods, they are for implementing the custom transform in the example app. The only methods that are required are numberOfItemsInCarousel: and carousel:viewForItemAtIndex:reusingView:, everything else is optional.